# Calculate the maximum number of characters in the regex

Tags: javascript, regex

For example, we have the following regex:

```
/^[a-z]{1,10}-[0-9]{10}$/
```

This regex allows us to enter a maximum of 21 characters.

Is there an easy way to get number of maximum allowed characters in JavaScript?

Comment: What number, an inputs value ?

Comment: `var theNumberYouWant = 21`

Comment: are you wanting to detect the number of allowed characters based solely on the regular expression?

Comment: I want to get the maximum number of characters allowed by regex.

Comment: more questions, maybe a regex inside a regex. inception

Comment: Did you think about simple expressions as `a+` ? What about `(?:a{2}){4}` ? I think you would need a parser for this.

Comment: The answer is no! There is no easy way to get the number of characters that regex would allow, the easiest would be to construct a loop that tests the regex agains an increasing number of characters until it fails.

Comment: @adeneo: I don't think that works either, for more complex regex.

Comment: @adeneo: …but replace every single-character expression with a `.` before to match any strings of certain length (not just the specific language)? What about HamZa's example? It would fail for 1, but allow 8 characters…

Comment: @inetbug I think you will need to narrow down the scope. Are all regexes written in JS flavor ? How complex will the regex be ? And more importantly, what have you tried ?

Comment: @Bergi - Didn't think of that, you'd have to know that the regex would fail on a length of 1, and then you're just as screwed, as you'd have to read the regex with your eyes or parse it to know that, so automation isn't really viable unless you know what the regex does, and why would you need to test it if you can just read it and see what it does.

Comment: Yes, you should use a parser (actually it would be a quite trivial one) :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't.

If you use "?" or "+" or "*" you can't guess how many characters will match.

Comment: Well he wants the max of characters that could be matched. So `max('a?') is 1`, `max('a+') is infinite` and `max('a*') is infinite as well`

Comment: Your example is very simple. Good luck to write a function which will count the maximum of characters when it's not infinite